# iOS5: How to use a UIActionSheet object in an NSObject class and cause it to appear in another view?

Tags: ios, class, nib, nsobject

I have a common method that causes a "Contact Us" (UIActionSheet) message to appear.  As I am using the same code in multiple classes, I am trying to move to its own class (I used NSObject class type).

The question is, how do I get the UIActionSheet to appear in the NIB of the class that requires it?

I am using this code in the NSObject class:

```
    UIActionSheet *msg = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                      initWithTitle:@"Consultation Request" 
                      delegate:self 
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"  
                      destructiveButtonTitle:nil  
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Email",@"Text",@"Office Phone", nil];

msg.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;

[msg showInView:self.view];
```

Obviously the last line is wrong because the "view" is the NIB of the originating class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 options.

### 1. Property

You can use property to tell your `NSObject` where it should display your action sheet:

```
///// MyObject.h

@property (nonatomic, strong /* or rerain if not ARC */) UIView *viewForActionSheet;

//// MyObject.m

@synthesize viewForActionSheet;

...

[msg showInView:self.viewForActionSheet];


//// MyViewController.m

MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
obj.viewForActionSheet = self.view;
[obj presentMyActionSheet];
```

### 2. Delegate

This is more advanced way that uses obj-c protocol (a.k.a. delegate)

```
//// MyObject.h

@protocol MyObjectDelegate <NSObject>
@required

- (UIView *)viewForActionSheet;

@end;

@interface MyObject : NSObject

...

@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained /* or assign if not ARC */) id <MyObjectDelegate> delegate;

@end

//// MyObject.m

@synthesize delegate;

...

[msg showInView:self.delegate.viewForActionSheet];

//// MyViewController.m

- (UIView *)viewForActionSheet {
    return self.view;
}
```

### 3. Window

The easiest way, but not the safest one

```
//// MyObject.m

[msg showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use window to show the action sheet. In that case you don't actually need any view. Wherever you want the action sheet, just show it over the window (ofcourse if you don't need any view, inside the action of the buttons of the action sheet).